# Rewrite URL from HTTPS (Non-SSL Domain) to HTTPS (SSL Domain) Throws 404 Error

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, iis

I have an IIS website *(ISAPI Rewrite 3)* with two domain aliases:

- example.com *(primary domain)*
- example.net
- example.org

Example.com has an SSL cert.  The others do not.

Consequently, I want to forward all HTTP **and** HTTPS traffic to HTTPS://EXAMPLE.COM.  My .htaccess rules work fine except when requesting HTTPS://EXAMPLE.NET or HTTPS://EXAMPLE.ORG - it generates a 404 error.  If I request HTTP://EXAMPLE.NET, HTTP://EXAMPLE.ORG, or HTTP://EXAMPLE.COM, .htaccess works fine - all requests are forwarded to HTTPS://EXAMPLE.COM.

Here's my super-simple .HTACCESS directive:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.(com|net|org)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it?  Is the server intercepting secure requests for insecure domains and throwing a 404 before processing .htaccess?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't used IIS in a while (that's windows Dev I believe), but the RewriteCond and RewriteRule are seen in apache on linux as well. Is there a selector previous to the conditions?

Try this url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

Comment: @Millar248 The question itself refers to a third party IIS extension, https://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/

Comment: Unrelated to this specific error but related to what you ultimately want to do: You cannot access a domain with HTTPS which has no valid certificate. Since redirect means to access the domain first you also cannot issue a HTTPS redirect from a domain which has no certificate to a domain which does. You can redirect from plain HTTP for this non-certificate domain, but not from HTTPS.

Comment: Where exactly are you using this rule? Are there any other preceding conditions? Do you have any other directives? Taken out of context, the rule you've posted doesn't really make sense as it appears to redirect to itself and would therefore result in a redirect loop, unless it is only being applied to HTTP traffic for some reason (which appears to be the case)? The fact that `https://example.net` and `https://example.org` result in a 404 would appear to suggest they resolve to the wrong place, so there is an error in your config for the domain aliases?

Comment: Thank you, Steffen.  I believe that answers my question.  As for the 404 errors, it appears to be a Wordpress issue.  In fact, I'm experiencing all sorts of issues with Wordpress and non-Wordpress content sharing the same hosting server.  Wordpress appears to be a pig and doesn't let .htaccess do it's thing before redirecting users to it's own content or, when no Wordpress content can be found, it throws a 404.  I've tried to override this behavior in Wordpress but, so far, nothing works.  And, I'm off topic anways.  Thank you, all for the helpful replies.

Comment: Although if this was a problem with not having a valid certificate then you wouldn't be getting a 404? If the cert was invalid then the browser wouldn't even connect to the server to begin with, without first getting a browser warning (if it connects at all). "Wordpress appears to be a pig and doesn't let .htaccess do it's thing" - Maybe IIS does something different in this regard, but otherwise, `.htaccess` is processed _before_ the request is even passed to PHP/WordPress. Maybe you have a front-end proxy that is intercepting the request?